# How to change regression line aesthetics in GGPLOT

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 2 continuous variables I would like to show on a scatter plot (geom_point). These data are separated into 2 categories (high and low, for example). I would like to create a regression line for both conditions (so far so good).
I would like to distinguish the regression lines by one being dashed and the other being solid (this is for a publication, so it needs to be black and white).
I can only distinguish them by colour (using the code below), which is no good to me.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=continuous_variable_1, y=continuous_variable_2, color=category)) +
  geom_point() +
   geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE)
```

Is there a way to separate the data into categories whereby the points have different shapes and the regression lines are dashed vs. solid?

Any help is very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You could map your categorical variable on the `linetype` or `lty` aes and set the `color` to `black` in `geom_smooth`. And if you want different shapes then map your categorical variable on the `shape` aes too.

Using `mtcars` as example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg, lty = factor(am), shape = factor(am))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE, color = "black")
#> `geom_smooth()` using formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the swift response and solution! Much appreciated.

Comment: hi, @stefan ! your answer helped me as well, thanks! But I'm struggling  with the legends,  would you look it up? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74336313/match-legend-color-line-type-and-shape-according-to-a-group-ggplot2  I don't know how to make the shapes appear on the legends